# How to compress large files using DeflaterOutputStream?

Tags: java, compression, deflate

I don't see anything wrong with my code, but whenever I check for the size of the compressed file in the destination location, I only see that the file size has only been reduced by 2 or 3KB which is way too less for large files scaling to around 650MB.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("filetobecompressed.mp4");
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("compressedfile.mp4");
    DeflaterOutputStream dout = new DeflaterOutputStream(fout);
    byte b[] = new byte[8192];
    int r;
    float tracker = 0;
    while((r=fin.read(b))!=-1)
    {
        dout.write(b,0,r);
        dout.flush();
        tracker += (float)r/1000000f;
        System.out.println(tracker + "MB compressed");
    }
    dout.finish();
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    dout.close();
    System.out.println("Compression successful");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW each time you call `flush()` you add a bit of data with compressed files. It brings to a conclusion anything it is working on at that point.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to compress an MP4 file.  The MP4 file format(s) typically do their own compression, so there is no redundancy for a general (lossless) compressor to eliminate.

Try compressing the same file using a command-line compression utility.  I predict that you will minimal compression there as well.

The only way you could get further compression for an (already) compressed audio / video file would be to use the codecs for the format to decompress and then recompress at a lower quality.  Obviously, you sacrifice audio / video quality in doing this.